A codeql sensitive configuration detection problem
My company's development project uses yml files as configuration files. How can I use codeql to detect whether these yml files contain sensitive information such as plain text passwords?
When I created the codeql database, I used the parameter
--language=go, yaml,
but I don't know how to query the yaml database and whether this method is the right solution.

Assuming that you are also the author of https://github.com/github/codeql/issues/16755, please in the future cross-link the questions to avoid people spending time on answering this twice, and for future readers to make it easier to find the answer.

github.com/github/codeql/issues/16755
I asked the same question on github and got the solution.
This should be solved. We just need to create a javascript database and check the yaml configuration file through the javascript standard library provided by Codelql
